# session remains https even after a user logs out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, https, devise, authorization

My team has developed an app using RoR. We're using devise gem for authorization. The problem is that the user session remains https even after a user signs out. This is causing some problems with varnish.

Could someone please point out how can I change it so that the session is http instead of https after logging out.

Thanks

Comment: do you what to destroy your session or change it from https to http

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh : change it to http